# My gravatar has changed and I would like to get it back

Tags: support, bug, gravatar

Something has gone wrong with my gravatar. It has changed into the icon of user "Vera".

"Vera" is actually another account once made by me (with another e-mailadress) when I had no disposal of my own account, so there is some link that might be explaining. The e-mail adresses are different, but the part before @ is the same. Sometimes I make use of that account if I am in a sortlike situation.

Looking at "Vera" among the users I see that the corresponding gravatar there is now a sort of blank.

The picture down is visible for me when I am logged in as drhab. The picture down-right (preceded by drhab) is my original gravatar, and is not matching the picture up-left.

[image]

I would really like to get the original back, but do not know how to.

I am rather clumsey with computers etc. and help with this will be very much appreciated.

Comment: You know what? I think this is the same problem as [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/24916). The URL for your current avatar is `https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/d7bd627b8a9fca6487131c78c3a6a21d?s=328&d=identicon&r=PG` while the URL for the avatar from [an archived profile in the Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20150905174030/http://math.stackexchange.com/users/75923/drhab) is `https://web.archive.org/web/20150909212622im_/https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/d7bd627b8a9fca6487131c78c3a6a21d?s=328&d=identicon&r=PG`. That they have the same MD5 hash is telling.

Comment: Additionally, of the Veras I can find with a similar email address, the one that currently has a faded gravatar has always had that gravatar (at least if the Wayback Machine can be trusted). Other possible Veras weren't archived, so I can't say anything about them definitively. [This current gravatar](http://i.stack.imgur.com/pKF1Z.png) from another "Vera" has a similar color scheme, so perhaps you just misremember the details.

Comment: @arjafi Thanks!!! I managed to regain my own gravatar (I know that word since yesterday) by following your instructions. Also my (very poor) familiarity with imgur has grown a bit, which might be useful in the future.

Comment: I'm glad that worked. I think I'm going to mark this as a duplicate of the other thread, since as far as I can tell the two situations are the same.

Comment: Fine. Blank Vera (=drhab in disguise, Vera is the name of his 4-year old granddaughter) has been given a *new* gravatar by now.